# Braintree was unable to perform a charge: Custom field is invalid: description

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, braintree

we are using Laravel 5.2 with Cashier/Braintree.

We had a subscription based website which works find. These were for monthly recurring membership packages.

We are now trying to add in a single charge for a few days taster. It seems to all work fine until the last step when we get an error saying the description is invalid. Looking at the documentation and source code we are not able to find why this is not working.

Here is the code:

```
$plan = $request->get('plan');
$coupon = $request->get('coupon');
$user = $this->user;

if ( false === $user->hasBraintreeId() ){
    $customer = $user->createAsBraintreeCustomer($request->get('payment_method_nonce'), array());
    $user->setCustomerId($customer->id);
    $user->save();
} else {
    $customer = $user->asBraintreeCustomer();
}

if ( $plan == '5-day-taster' ){ // One off payment
    $this->user->invoiceFor('5-day-taster', 5.99);
} elseif ( $plan == '10-day-taster' ){ // One off payment
    $this->user->invoiceFor('10-day-taster', 9.99);
} elseif ( $plan == 'personal-standard' ){ // Subscription(s)
    if ( isset($coupon) && !empty($coupon) )
        $this->user->newSubscription($plan, $plan)
            ->withCoupon($coupon)
            ->create($request->get('payment_method_nonce'), [
                'email' => $this->user->email,
            ]);
    else
        $this->user->newSubscription($plan, $plan)
            ->create($request->get('payment_method_nonce'), [
                'email' => $this->user->email,
            ]);
}
```

We get the following error:

```
Exception in Billable.php line 41:
Braintree was unable to perform a charge: Custom field is invalid: description.
```

Source code from Braintree (not edited, just using for reference):

```
/**
     * Make a "one off" charge on the customer for the given amount.
     *
     * @param  int  $amount
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return \Braintree\Transaction
     */
    public function charge($amount, array $options = [])
    {
        $customer = $this->asBraintreeCustomer();

        $response = BraintreeTransaction::sale(array_merge([
            'amount' => $amount * (1 + ($this->taxPercentage() / 100)),
            'paymentMethodToken' => $customer->paymentMethods[0]->token,
            'options' => [
                'submitForSettlement' => true,
            ],
            'recurring' => true,
        ], $options));

        if (! $response->success) {
            throw new Exception('Braintree was unable to perform a charge: '.$response->message);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Invoice the customer for the given amount.
     *
     * @param  string  $description
     * @param  int  $amount
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return \Braintree\Transaction
     */
    public function invoiceFor($description, $amount, array $options = [])
    {
        return $this->charge($amount, array_merge($options, [
            'customFields' => [
                'description' => $description,
            ],
        ]));
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any advice given.

Answer (score 7):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

It looks like Laravel\Cashier has an undocumented requirement for you to [setup a custom field in your Braintree control panel](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/custom-fields). It appears to be blowing up because you don't have this custom field, and it's trying to use it to store data.

I tried to find something in the [Laravel\Cashier Documentation for Braintree configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#braintree-configuration) but I only found a line about other methods where they link to some unrelated part of [Braintree documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/php). But the [Braintree Custom Fields docs](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/custom-fields) say:

1. Log into the Control Panel
2. Navigate to Settings > Processing > Custom Fields
3. Next to Fields, click the desired field
4. On the editing form, you can change the field's Display name or toggle between Store and Pass Back and Pass Thru
5. Click Save

It should get past this error when you add a custom field named `description` in your control panel with `Store and Pass Back` set.